# What does `cat passwd | awk -F':' '{printf $1}'` do?

Tags: command-line

What does this command do? How do I see that in the terminal because I don't have anything when I write `cat passwd | awk -F':' '{printf $1}'`

Answer (score 4):

`cat passwd` outputs the contents of a file named `passwd` in the current directory. The `awk` command then parses it, splits each line with `:` as the field separator and prints the first field.

If you don't get any output, either:

- there is no file named `passwd` in the current directory
- there is a file, but it is empty
- there is a file, but the first fields of all lines in it are empty (the lines begin with `:`).

What the command presumably is meant to do is parse `/etc/passwd`. In which case, you can do:

```
awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Further, unless you want to restrict the command to local accounts, uses `getent passwd` instead of using the `/etc/passwd` file:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume this is a malformed command to extract all usernames from the system:

- `cat passwd` prints the output of the file `passwd`, presumably `/etc/passwd`.
- `awk -F':' {printf $1}` separates the input (given by cat) using `:` as a delimiter and then only prints the first token, i.e. the username.

It doesn't work because `/etc` is not in the path variable by default, so the path would have to be given, not just the file name. Also, the result wouldn't be parsable properly, as awk's `printf` doesn't put newlines at the end, as opposed to `print`.

The IMO correct command would look like this:

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F':' '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Whether or not `/etc` is in the `$PATH` variable is irrelevant here; you would have to use the full path or `cd` into `/etc` or otherwise make it your current working directory (`pwd`) for `cat passwd` to work. `$PATH` variable only applies to executables like the program `cat` itself.